# Type method in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I come across below statement in various JS code where first a function let's say "test" is declared thereafter used as mentioned below:

type: "test"

Please explain what does this statement mean where "test" is a function name.

Sample code below:

```
var MyFavoritesAjax = Class.create();
MyFavoritesAjax.prototype = Object.extendsObject(AbstractAjaxProcessor, {

    ajaxFunction_getFavorites : function() {

        var result = this.newItem("result");

        result.setAttribute("message", "returning all favorites");

        this._addFavorite("color", "blue");
        this._addFavorite("beer", "lager");
        this._addFavorite("pet", "dog");

    },

    _addFavorite : function(name, value) {
        var favs = this.newItem("favorite");
        favs.setAttribute("name", name);
        favs.setAttribute("value", value);
    },

    type : "MyFavoritesAjax"

});
```

Comment: "test" is a string here, not a function name. Please show the whole code.

Comment: Can you please add some context to your question? Sample code, or anything...

Comment: +4 for this question? What are people thinking?

Comment: I cant understand what is special in this question to have +4.  The information is insufficient

Comment: @thesystem I assume the thought process goes "I don't understand the question --> must be something really advanced --> +1"

Comment: var MyFavoritesAjax = Class.create();
MyFavoritesAjax.prototype = Object.extendsObject(AbstractAjaxProcessor, {
 
 ajaxFunction_getFavorites : function() {

  var result = this.newItem("result");
 
  result.setAttribute("message", "returning all favorites");

  this._addFavorite("color", "blue");
  this._addFavorite("beer", "lager");
  this._addFavorite("pet", "dog");
 
 },
 
 _addFavorite : function(name, value) {
  var favs = this.newItem("favorite");
  favs.setAttribute("name", name);
  favs.setAttribute("value", value);
 },
 
 type : "MyFavoritesAjax"
 
});

Comment: @Juhana: :-) That could be it.

Comment: @user1934643: Are you asking about the syntax of `property:value`? Or are you asking about that specific use of the `type:` property? If the latter, there's no special meaning in JavaScript for a property named `type:`. It may have some meaning for the specific 3rd party API used. But to be clear, the `extendsObject` method isn't native JavaScript. It's part of some code library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you've shown the rest of the code:

```
type : "MyFavoritesAjax"
```

is a property declaration on an object being passed to `Object.extendsObject()`.  It creates a property on that object named `"type"` and gives it a value of `"MyFavoritesAjax"`.

This is similar to the other properties on that same object `ajaxFunction_getFavorites` and `_addFavorite`, though they have function references as their value instead of a string.

Comment: so that means 'type' property in this code just has a string value (MyFavoritesAjax) as mentioned and, not the overall outcome of function MyFavoritesAjax.

Please let me know if I am getting right...

Comment: It's just an argument being passed to `Object.extendsObject()` which is going to become a property on `MyFavoritesAjax.prototype`.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable input and support...

Answer (score 0):

Given what you posted, you have a [label statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) (with the label `type`) including a simple expression [statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Statements) consisting of the sole [string literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#String_literals) `"test"`. You could (and should) add a semicolon after it. However,

```
type: "text";
```

does not make much sense, it neither has any effects when executing nor does the label identify a loop.

---

Ah, your code example sheds some more light on this. As expected, you have an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals) that is passed to the `Object.extendsObject` function:

```
{
    type : "MyFavoritesAjax"
}
```

Here, "`type`" is the property name and the `"MyFavoritesAjax"` string the property value. What this function does with it, and what it *means* in that contexts, should be documented with that function. I don't know it, it's not native.

Comment: I think the OP is showing a fragment of object declaration. Can't be sure before seeing a complete example though. *edit:* yup, that was it.

Comment: @Juhana: I guessed that as well, but I answered what was asked. Now with proper explanation of the actual code, so you can remove the downvote :-)

Comment: Sorry, wasn't me. I can upvote to counter though.